# rails show content outside yield only for admin controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I put this code on the /views/layouts/application.html.erb
I would like it to be above the `<%= yield %>` because I want it to be like a header, but only for the admin controller.

So I have this code that was on my admin views, But I would like to move it to the application.html.erb so I won't need to repeat that code

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>

  <%= current_user.email %>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>

    <hr>        
        <ul class="admin-nav">
            <li rel="posts">Posts</li>
            <li rel="pages">Pages</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>        

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way here is probably going to be using [a nested layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) which basically allows Rails to call a layout specific to your `AdminController` (you'll put it inside `app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb`) and within that file to define a [`content_for`](http://devdocs.io/rails/actionview/helpers/capturehelper#method-i-content_for) block that are also referred to in your main layout, and then rendering that main layout.

### Update showing example

#### app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb

```
<% content_for :admin do %>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= current_user.email %>
    <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>

    <hr>        
      <ul class="admin-nav">
        <li rel="posts">Posts</li>
        <li rel="pages">Pages</li>
      </ul>
    <hr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

#### app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%# other stuff for your layout %>

<body>
  <%= content_for?(:admin) ? yield(:admin) : yield %>
</body>
```

Comment: OK, so I did that: <% content_for :admin do %> and then on my application.html.erb I wrote that: <%= yield :admin %>, so what's the difference between that or if I get rid of the yield :admin ?

Comment: If you get rid of the `yield :admin` then it won't display the `content_for :admin` anymore.

Comment: You didn't get it, What's the difference between using the yield or just putting the (static) content on my admin view?

Comment: Well, you'd need to put that content in every view for your admin controller, instead of in just one place for the whole controller.

Comment: Just updated my answer with a full example, basically copying from the link I gave you, hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try that

Answer (score 2):

In your **/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

Put this inside you header tag

```
<%= yield :admin_only %>
```

And, in your other page that renders data to be put in layout header, do like:

```
<% content_for :admin_only do %>        
......data here ... 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you see the question that I wrote on the other answer comment ?

Comment: @aldrien.h it's better to do as I mentioned and use the nested layout because with your suggestion they'll need to repeat that same `content_for :admin_only` block in every view for that controller (the OP wants the header for all actions in a given controller).

Comment: I think you both said the same thing, @aldrien.h just show me exactly how to write it

Comment: Subtle difference because this answer is talking about putting that `content_for` in "your other page", rather than in the admin controller layout.

Comment: that's fine, i guess i need both of the answers, unless you would explain also how to write the content_for :admin, but I understood it also before he wrote it here, because I searched on the guide of rails how to do that, and it's exactly like he wrote here, both answers were useful, thanks